# Can Merciful Spell be used on summon monster spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage, summoning, metamagic

Im in a game where its not always the best idea to deal lethal damage. Basically those who rule are corrupt but not the town guard doing their best to keep the city safe. So trying not to kill the town guards and stuff.

[Merciful spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/merciful-spell-metamagic) is wonderful in that regard.

> You can alter spells that inflict damage to inflict nonlethal damage instead. Spells that inflict damage of a particular type (such as fire) inflict nonlethal damage of that same type.

But how would merciful spell affect the [summon monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) spells? Would they now deal nonlethal damage? Could summons even normally deal [nonlethal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Nonlethal-Damage) by taking the -4 on their natural attack rolls?

Answer (score 6):

Summon Monster doesn't deal direct damage, then Merciful Spell has no effect on it. The rules aren't specific about the type of lethal weapon that can deal nonlethal damage with a -4 penalty on the attack roll, then maybe any creature smart enough to understand the concept of nonlethal attacks (probably anything smarter than an animal) can do this with natural weapons. This should be discussed with your GM.

Comment: Also, as long as the summoned creature can understand you - you can command it to distract, trip, pin (etc. etc.) the target rather than attack it.